# ViewPager update Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            if(position == 1)
            {
                new FragmentFavorites().update(getApplicationContext());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

**update** from **FragmentFavorites**

```
public void update(Context context) {
    savedFacts = com.invizorys.sexpro.util.Util.readFactsList(context);

    if (savedFacts.size() > 0)
        mTextView.setText(savedFacts.get(currentFactIndex));
    else
        mTextView.setText("you still have not saved any fact");
}
```

when I turn on FragmentFavorites application crashes(mTextView nullpointer), despite the fact that I find it in onCreateView()

```
mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_fact);
```

**Update**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);
    ...
    mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_fact);
    ...
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you inflate `rootView` and are you sure the `rootView` is actually the correct view that holds the `textview_fact`?

Comment: everything works fine if I do not call **update**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you new a FragmentFavorites instance, the onCreateView() is not called yet. You should find the FragmentFavorites instance from ViewPager instead of creating one.